# Отображение картинки из интернета в ImageView

Tags: android, url

Хочу создать ImageView в котором будет отображаться картинка из интернета (хочу использовать URL).

Answer (score 4):

Нужно подключить библиотеку Picasso

```
Picasso.with(this) // если фрагмент getActivity()
                .load(url) // ссылка на изображение 
                .placeholder(R.drawable.web_hi_res_512)
                .error(R.drawable.web_hi_res_512) // если не удалось загрузить картинку, ставить картинку по стандарту
                .into(imageView); // указываем imageView куда будем выводить картинку
```